# PyQGIS - importing features selected by location from online GeoJSON file

Tags: pyqgis, geojson, topology, select-by-location

There is a large GeoJSON file stored online with thousands of geometries and I have created and stored a simple polygon .shp file that is the area of interest.
Is there a way to use PyQGIS to import into a QGIS project **only** the GeoJSON features that are within the polygon shapefile, as if it was a simple `selectByLocation`?

I know that the code part for the `selectByLocation` would be:

```
parameters = {'INPUT':'layer','PREDICATE':[0],'INTERSECT':'polygon','METHOD':0}
processing.run("qgis:selectbylocation", parameters)
```

but I don't know how to manage the selection of features from an online source.

Comment: GeoJSON does not support any kind of indexing, so for applying the filter the whole GeoJSON file must be read. The code can then throw away the extra data, but it does not give any speed-up.

Comment: @user30184, so should I import and visualize the GeoJSON first, and then select-discard the data? In this case I will try again and maybe edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Visualizing the data is an unnecessary step but whatever process you are using it must do just that: download whole GeoJSON data, select what is needed, and discard all the rest.